# Jira Cloud + Bamboo: integration problems

Tags: jira, bamboo

Good day.

We have Jira Cloud + Bitbucket Cloud + Bamboo on demand.

Seems that integration work fine - in Jira issues at development section we can see activity in repositories: branch, commits and pull request updating and show everything normally.

At Bamboo server we also can see activity cross links for Jira issues.

But at Jira issue we can not see any information about builds from Bamboo.

Application links connected, no any messages about problems on Jira or Bamboo side.

Please help to solve this problem

[image]
[image]